# 192.168.1.xxx devices cannot ping to 192.168.0.xxx with same subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Tags: networking, ip-address

I am not a network person but do take care of a church's network. Now we need to setup a NAS file server that needs to be accessible by all 192.168.1.xxx devices.

Since the Netgear WNDR800 router owned by the church has all 4 LAN ports used up, so I hook up the server to 1 of the 3 empty LAN ports for the TPLink Router (green in attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1oy6.jpg)) that is supplied by the ISP (need to return to the ISP once no more buying Internet service from them).

The server get an IP 192.168.0.xxx once hooked to TPLink but all church owned devices with IP 192.168.1.xxx cannot communicate with this server. I am not sure what's missing.

Comment: "The server get an IP 192.168.0.xxx" - By Server do you mean NAS? It sounds as if the default gateway in the NAS is preset, so I would advise digging out the NAS manual to determine how to edit the default gateway value to 192.168.1.xxx

Comment: You have the WAN port on the WNDR3800 connected to the LAN port on the TPLink router. Similarly, you have the TPLink router's WAN port connected to the Fiber Router's LAN port. This creates a confusing combination of multiple LANs that is completely unnecessary and counterproductive. You should have one LAN unless there are good grounds for separation and the consequences of such separation are well understood.

Comment: The fiber router and the TPLink router belong to the ISP that I cannot manage, ISP tech people come in and set these 2 devices up then use a LAN cable to connect from the TPLink router LAN port to the church owned Netgear WNDR3800 WAN port while we changed the service requesting for fiber connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Router creates a new network for all LAN ports and redirects traffic based on NAT rules to the WAN port.

Because your situation has 2 routers, you have 2 different networks. Because one router is connected to the wan port of another router, these networks are shielded from eachother. You can do a lot with portforwarding, but unfortunately not enough.

What you need to do is buy a network switch to extend the amount of ports from the netgear router. You unplug one network cable from the netgear router, plug the switch into it, and plug the removed cable back into the switch. You then plugin the NAS into another free LAN port on the switch.

If you have another router laying around, you can use it as a switch, as long as you don't use the WAN port. Unfortunately for your situation, you cannot change the Netgear router to accomodate this because that means you have to do all the configuration through the TP Link switch, which you don't manage.

Comment: You are correct that I cannot manage the TPLink router loaned from the ISP since we are not given the admin password for this router. I also think installing a network switch to the Netgear router to give more ports should fix the problem but I can't explain why & glad that you shed the light what is the reason behind. Thanks